# Composer use local relative repo

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I am trying to load a git repository locally stored in my localhost env.

Lets say I have a project called: "A" and it is a composer package registered in packagist.
When I try to use it in a project called "B" like this:

```
"require": {
    "package/A": "dev-master"
}
```

it works great! The package is fetched and there are no problems. except that package A is still under development by another team and changes are made non-stop. my package B should be up to date with the latest code.

what I did is created a shared drive in our network and it hosts all the packages.
it looks like this:

```
Drive E
--- A
------ Some files
------ composer.json
--- B
------ Some files
------ composer.json
```

We all work in the same drive so i won't have to wait until packagist will be updated, I decided load the repository locally relative to the path and load the package also locally.

```
"require": {
    "package/A": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type":"git",
        "url":"../A"
    }
],
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "A":"../A"
    }
}
```

At first it worked. after some time (and I don't remember doing anything) i started to get errors from composer that the path is not valid. so I changed to path to full path:

```
"url":"E:\A"
```

and it worked also for some time. after it also stopped working and now I can't find a way to load a locally stored git repository with relative path.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

You set composer path in local environment from your pc .it is in right click on my computer then you get it and set the composer path .
Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understood your answer. what exactly I should do?